# Write and read problem while interfacing 93LC46B EEPROM through SPI

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, eeprom

I try to save and read data from 93LC46B EEPROM using SPI with Arduino UNO.
I'm following this article https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SPIEEPROM .
So far I have correctly connected EEPROM pinout (as shown in 93LC46B EEPROM datasheet) with arduino MISO, MOSI, SS, CLK, I copied the code from link and here is the problem, I cant save data to EEPROM, it should be filled with buffer but it is not, whats more everytime I try to read data there are different values on same addresses. How can i solve this problem ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your circuit and the relevant code and what you see going wrong and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that 93LC46B is not compatible with AT25HP512. You can not use that tutorial. There are many differences.

Have a look at this blog instead: http://owlsan.blogspot.com/2012/10/accessing-93c4693c46n-serial-eeprom.html